# Every time I run the declare statement it says it encountered the end to file symbol

Tags: sql, database, oracle

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

--VARIABLE DECLARATION
DECLARE
c_name VARCHAR(30); (Here it gives the end to file error)
p_purchaed VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
CURSOR( c_CustProd IS SELECT (C.cust_fName ||',' || C.cust_lName) AS "CUSTOMER", P.product_name (and then the select statement it says it was expecting a not null statment)
FROM Billing B
JOIN Product_Billing PB ON B.bill_ID = PB.bill_ID,
JOIN Customer C on B.cust_ID = C.cust_ID,
JOIN Product P on PB.product_ID = P.product_ID,
WHERE P.product_price > 10000
ORDER BY P.product_name DESC, P.product_price DESC);



OPEN c_CustProd;
LOOP
FETCH c_CustProd into c_name, p_purchaed

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CUSTOMER:    '||c_name);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PRODUCT:     '||p_purchaed );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-------------------------------');
\
END LOOP
CLOSE c_CustProd;
END;
```

I am still new to oracle. but i have to just display a customers name and what they purchased.
i have inserted all the variables earlier on in the code and everything is working but this statement and i dont know where all the errors are

Comment: By the way, it's not a 'declare statement', it's  a PL/SQL anonymous block, and `declare` begins a section within it. And, it's not 'the end to file error', it's *PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:* followed by a list of expected keywords. It means it got to the end without finding something it needed, like a closing `end if` or the end of a loop.

Answer (score 4):

Quite a few errors, I'll try to mention them all:

- use `varchar2`, not `varchar`
- cursor should be declared within the `declare` section, not after `begin`
- remove superfluous parenthesis from the cursor
- don't use double quotes while naming *anything* in Oracle (not an error, but ... not a benefit either. More kind of *pain*, later)
- you never exited the loop
- what's that backslash `\` doing in your code?
- statements have to be terminated by semi-colon `;`

Compare this code to yours.

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2    c_name VARCHAR2(30);
  3    p_purchaed VARCHAR2(30);
  4
  5    CURSOR c_CustProd IS
  6      SELECT C.cust_fName ||',' || C.cust_lName AS CUSTOMER,
  7             P.product_name
  8      FROM Billing B
  9      JOIN Product_Billing PB ON B.bill_ID = PB.bill_ID
 10      JOIN Customer C on B.cust_ID = C.cust_ID
 11      JOIN Product P on PB.product_ID = P.product_ID
 12      WHERE P.product_price > 10000
 13      ORDER BY P.product_name DESC, P.product_price DESC;
 14  BEGIN
 15    OPEN c_CustProd;
 16    LOOP
 17      FETCH c_CustProd into c_name, p_purchaed;
 18      EXIT when c_custprod%notfound;
 19
 20      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CUSTOMER:    '||c_name);
 21      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PRODUCT:     '||p_purchaed );
 22      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-------------------------------');
 23    END LOOP;
 24    CLOSE c_CustProd;
 25  END;
 26  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you. I managed to find the errors and then saw your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time you do not need an explicitly named cursor or variables, and the more compact syntax is preferable:

```
begin
    for r in (
        select c.cust_fname || ',' || c.cust_lname as customer_name
             , p.product_name as product_purchased
        from   billing b
               join product_billing pb on pb.bill_id = b.bill_id
               join customer c on c.cust_id = b.cust_id
               join product p on p.product_id = pb.product_id
        where  p.product_price > 10000
        order  by p.product_name  desc, p.product_price desc
    )
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line('CUSTOMER:    ' || r.customer_name);
        dbms_output.put_line('PRODUCT:     ' || r.product_purchased);
        dbms_output.put_line('--------------------------------');
    end loop;
end;
```